# Using pagedown to convert from HTML to pdf in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, pagedown

Its my first time using pagedown.

Could you help me?

This is my .Rmd code:

````
---
title: "Table"
output:
  html_document:
    css: "test.css"
---

```{r}
library(knitr)
data(iris)
kable(iris)
```
````

This is my .css file:

```
.main-container { 
     max-width: 1600px !important;
 } 
 tr:nth-child(even) {
     background-color: #f2f2f2;
 }
 th {
     background-color: #FF6319;
     color: white;
     font-size: 12px;
 }
 tbody {
     font-size: 12px;
 }
 hr {
     page-break-after: always;
 }
```

When i set the command `pagedown::chrome_print('C:/Users/user/Downloads/myfile.html')` the pdf output is created but it doesn mantain the css style.

What am I missing?

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: You can try setting the format in chrome_print as pdf.... check https://rdrr.io/cran/pagedown/man/chrome_print.html
Another option would be using rmarkdown? rmarkdown::pandoc_convert("C:/Users/user/Downloads/myfile.html", output = "test.pdf")

Comment: @spYder you mean `pagedown::chrome_print('C:/Users/user/Downloads/myfile.html', format="pdf)` ? I did and didnt work.

Comment: @spYder I also use `rmarkdown::pandoc_convert`and it didnt work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior comes from print [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries): the `rmarkdown::html_document()` output format defines different CSS rules for print and screen. Secondly, the `pagedown::chrome_print()` function uses the print media styles to generate PDF.

The `rmarkdown::html_document()` output format relies on Bootstrap 3.3.5 which defines some specific rules for print media, [see the source code](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/dd8d420e8b0d50ee87a2960bd573cc6484d32e66/inst/rmd/h/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css#L191-L262).

More precisely, in the source code, there is this declaration:

```css
@media print {
  .table td, .table th {
    background-color: #fff !important;
  }
}
```

These rules override the CSS rules defined in the question for print media.

In order to obtain the expected behavior, you have to override these built-in CSS rules using a higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

This modified stylesheet should do the trick:

```
.main-container { 
     max-width: 1600px !important;
 } 
 .table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
     background-color: #f2f2f2 !important;
 }
 .table thead th {
     background-color: #FF6319 !important;
     color: white !important;
     font-size: 12px;
 }
 tbody {
     font-size: 12px;
 }
 hr {
     page-break-after: always;
 }
```